# Can not connect to SSL Socket IO Server

Tags: node.js, react-native, ssl, https, socket.io

I'm try to upgrade my SocketIO connection with SSL in order to get a secure traffic between client and server.
Currently there is a crossplatform application using React-Native. In order to communicate with the Server I'd like to use SocketIO. So far so good, everything worked for now, but without secure. The Server is running on an Ubuntu PC and it's a simple node.js SocketIO Server.
Draft of which worked fine:

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const WS_Server = new Server();

// event fired every time a new client connects:
WS_Server.on("connection", async (socket) => {
    console.info(`Client connected [id=${socket.id}]`);
});

WS_Server.listen(12123);
```

There the connection between Client and Server works absolutly fine.
But when I try to create a HTTPS Server and attach the SocketIO on it, I cant get a connection.
SocketIO Server with HTTPS:

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";

//SSL Verschlüsselung
import express from "express";
import * as https from 'https';
import * as fs from 'fs';

const app = express();

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('HELLO FROM SSL SERVER')
})

const WSS_Server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/cert.pem'),
},app);


const WS_Server = new Server(WSS_Server);

// event fired every time a new client connects:
WS_Server.on("connection", async (socket) => {
    console.info(`Client connected [id=${socket.id}]`);  
});

WSS_Server.listen(12123, () => {
    console.log('SSL Server listening on *:12123');
});
```

But when I try do connect to the URL: `'https://domain:12123'` I receive the `'HELLO FROM SSL SERVER'` message from the HTTPS Server, so i think the HTTPS Server also works fine and the browser also shows a secure connection.

Where could be the misstake?